# If it's worth to buy SLC SSD for low-end CPU and SATA II in terms of performance?

Tags: ssd, cpu

I have Dell Optiplex 330 and I wonder if on this PC SLC SSD would have any difference from other cheaper types of SSD.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshot does not say what drive you currently are using, but that said, if its not an SSD, but a traditional HDD, then it does not really matter what the new SSD is, you will ALWAYS get an improvement.

That said, the specs for your computer are really on the low end here. You will definitely be bottlenecked by the little amount of memory and the slow CPU. The SSD will help, but you may want to consider looking for a new computer that may already have the SSD, and then its not a good idea to upgrade the SSD now.

Also, if you currently already have an SSD and want to replace it with another SSD, then definitely don't. Given it is driven by a SATA connection, the maximum speed of 600mbps that SATA offers will already be mostly reached, so the speed increase, if its there, is going to be marginally, and the bottleneck described above will most likely not make it noticable anyway.